# determine chain of predecessors and successor from a list of first predecessor in python

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graph-databases

I have a list like the following

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | first_predecessor |
+----+-------------------+
|  0 | 4                 |
|  1 | 5                 |
|  2 | 6                 |
|  3 | 17,18             |
|  4 | 7                 |
|  5 | 8                 |
|  6 | 9                 |
|  7 | 10,11,12          |
|  8 | 13,14,15          |
|  9 | 16                |
| 10 | Input             |
| 11 | Input             |
| 12 | Input             |
| 13 | Input             |
| 14 | Input             |
| 15 | Input             |
| 16 | Input             |
| 17 | 19                |
| 18 | 20                |
| 19 | 21                |
| 20 | 22                |
| 21 | Input             |
+----+-------------------+
```

One item can have multiple immediate incoming ids, like in case of id=3, which is imediately preceeded by id=17 and id=18.
I need a python code to determine this result by following the chain of predecessors both ways:
(it is best to read the column all_successors to understand the logic, all_predecessors is the same logic backwards)

```
+----+-------------------+------------------+----------------+
| id | first_predecessor | all_predecessors | all_successors |
+----+-------------------+------------------+----------------+
|  0 | 4                 | 4,7,10,11,12     |                |
|  1 | 5                 | 5,8,13,14,15     |                |
|  2 | 6                 | 6,9,16           |                |
|  3 | 17,18             | 19,21,20,22      |                |
|  4 | 7                 | 7,10,11,12       | 0              |
|  5 | 8                 | 8,13,14,15       | 1              |
|  6 | 9                 | 9,16             | 2              |
|  7 | 10,11,12          | 10,11,12         | 0,4            |
|  8 | 13,14,15          | 13,14,15         | 1,5            |
|  9 | 16                | 16               | 2,6            |
| 10 | Input             |                  | 0,4,7          |
| 11 | Input             |                  | 0,4,7          |
| 12 | Input             |                  | 0,4,7          |
| 13 | Input             |                  | 1,5,8          |
| 14 | Input             |                  | 1,5,8          |
| 15 | Input             |                  | 1,5,8          |
| 16 | Input             |                  | 2,6,9          |
| 17 | 19                | 19,21            | 3              |
| 18 | 20                | 20,22            | 3              |
| 19 | 21                | 21               | 3,17           |
| 20 | 22                | 22               | 3,18           |
| 21 | Input             |                  | 3,17,19        |
| 22 | Input             |                  | 3,18,20        |
+----+-------------------+------------------+----------------+
```

I need some kind of recursive solution, or should I use some graph package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following functions to find all predecessors and all successors.

- [`ancestors(G, source)`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors.html): Returns all nodes having a path to `source` in `G`.
- [`descendants(G, source)`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html): Returns all nodes reachable from `source` in `G`.

To run the following example, make sure you change `INPUT` in your `id` column to `NaN`.

```py
df_ = df.copy()

df_['first_predecessor'] = df_['first_predecessor'].str.split(',')
df_ = df_.explode('first_predecessor')
df_['first_predecessor'] = df_['first_predecessor'].fillna(-1).astype(int)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_, 'first_predecessor', 'id', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
G.remove_node(-1)

df['all_predecessors'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, sorted(nx.ancestors(G, x)))))
df['all_successors'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, sorted(nx.descendants(G, x)))))
```

```
print(df)

    id first_predecessor   all_predecessors all_successors
0    0                 4       4,7,10,11,12               
1    1                 5       5,8,13,14,15               
2    2                 6             6,9,16               
3    3             17,18  17,18,19,20,21,22               
4    4                 7         7,10,11,12              0
5    5                 8         8,13,14,15              1
6    6                 9               9,16              2
7    7          10,11,12           10,11,12            0,4
8    8          13,14,15           13,14,15            1,5
9    9                16                 16            2,6
10  10               NaN                             0,4,7
11  11               NaN                             0,4,7
12  12               NaN                             0,4,7
13  13               NaN                             1,5,8
14  14               NaN                             1,5,8
15  15               NaN                             1,5,8
16  16               NaN                             2,6,9
17  17                19              19,21              3
18  18                20              20,22              3
19  19                21                 21           3,17
20  20                22                 22           3,18
21  21               NaN                           3,17,19
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks a lot!